# Django: собственная модель авторизации

Tags: python, авторизация, django

День добрый! Немного запутался в модели авторизации пользователя из другой базы.

```
backends.py

class TestAuthenticationBackend(object):
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from system_accounts where is_deleted=0 and \
    login='{0}' and password='{1}'".format(username,password))
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    return user

views.py

def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
return auth_views.login(request, 'accounts/login.html')

settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.backends.TestAuthenticationBackend',)
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'backend'

Answer (score 1):

Не надо лезть в базу напрямую. Используйте ORM.

Comment: Нет желания описывать таблицы в models, хотел сразу на прямую.

Comment: поэтому и не работает

Comment: Понятно, тогда сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Эту ошибку исправил, как записать теперь сессию использую функцию 


       if user is not None:
          login(request, user)


вот такая ошибка:

The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: last_login

Comment: Ваша модель должна предоставлять некоторый интерфейс, чтобы работать юзером: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Читал, только ни хрена не понял. Как-то всё заморочено, логики уловить не могу.